# Niceness and priority processes on Linux system

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, scheduling, nice

I am looking for a way to modify a process' priority through command line.
I found the builtin (bash) `nice` and the command `renice` which allow to modify the niceness of the process, but not the actual priority which is calculated by the kernel.

Is there a command which allows to set the priority?
(Or am I confused between niceness and priority?)

Comment: Also see [Difference between nice value and priority in the top output](https://superuser.com/a/877353/167043)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The *priority* of a process in linux is dynamic: The longer it runs, the lower its priority will be. A process *runs* when its actually using the CPU - most processes on a typical Linux box just wait for I/O and thus do not count as *running*.

The priority is taken into account when there are more processes running than CPU cores available: Highest priority wins. But as the winning process loses its proirity over time, other processes will take over the CPU at some point.

`nice` and `renice` will add/remove some "points" from priority. A process which has a higher `nice` value will get lesser CPU time. Root can also set a negative `nice` value - the process gets more CPU time.

Example: There are two processes (1 and 2) calculating the halting problem and one CPU core in the system. Default is `nice 0`, so both processes get about half of the CPU time each. Now lets renice process 1 to value 10. Result: Process 2 gets a significant higher amount of cpu time as process 1.

Note: In modern desktops there is plenty CPU time available - they are fast these days. Unfortunately HDDs are still relativeley slow on random I/O, so even a *nice* process can generate enough I/O traffic to significantly slow down a system.

Comment: No you are not confused. In resent Linux there are other schedulers. @Turbo J described the default/normal/transnational scheduler. There are some other schedulers: Normal, Batch, Round-robin, FIFO. And also i/o: Normal, idle, best-effort, Real-time. Batch and idle are lower priority than normal, the others are above normal, be very careful with these (don't touch them).

Comment: What about `ionice`?