# Process priority in Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I am new to Linux kernel and I have got confused . Please can anyone give answer to my questions :

Q1 -> Is static priority of a thread changes or not ? If changes then how it changes ?

Q2 -> What is the default value of static priority and dynamic priority for a process     and thread in Linux kernel ?

Q3 -> What is the initial value of static priority and dynamic priority for a newly created thread and process?

Q4 -> When we talk about the priority of a process or thread (incrementing / decrementing priority , setting priority etc. ) , then which priority we are referring , is it static priority or dynamic priority ?

Comment: This a repeat question, answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163722/what-is-the-difference-among-three-priorities-used-in-linux-kernel/22165523#22165523

Comment: ..and Googling the exact title gives: 'About 455,000 results'.

Comment: ..and the code/data is open-source, so yo can go look at how it works.

Comment: ..or you can just post on SO and get the drones to do all your Googling,  and other research , for you.

Answer (score 0):

For currently running process, please run the below command

```
renice <priority_value> -p `pidof <process_name>`
```

Here, -20<=priority_value<=19

For new process

```
nice -n <priority_value> <process_name>
```